# Why can't I install Ninject 3.2.2 if my project targets MonoAndroid,Version=v5.1?

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, ninject

When installing Ninject I get this log from the Output in VS2015:

```
Attempting to gather dependencies information for package 'Ninject.3.2.2' with respect to project 'ProjectPhoenix.Droid', targeting 'MonoAndroid,Version=v5.1'
Attempting to resolve dependencies for package 'Ninject.3.2.2' with DependencyBehavior 'Lowest'
Resolving actions to install package 'Ninject.3.2.2'
Resolved actions to install package 'Ninject.3.2.2'
Attempting to gather dependencies information for package 'Ninject.3.2.2' with respect to project 'ProjectPhoenix.iOS', targeting 'Xamarin.iOS,Version=v1.0'
Attempting to resolve dependencies for package 'Ninject.3.2.2' with DependencyBehavior 'Lowest'
Resolving actions to install package 'Ninject.3.2.2'
Resolved actions to install package 'Ninject.3.2.2'
For adding package 'Ninject.3.2.2' to project 'ProjectPhoenix.Droid' that targets 'monoandroid51'.
Install failed. Rolling back...
Package 'Ninject 3.2.2.0' does not exist in project 'ProjectPhoenix.Droid'
Could not install package 'Ninject 3.2.2'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 'MonoAndroid,Version=v5.1', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.
========== Finished ==========
```

I'm working on Xamarin and the same project runs great on Xamarin Studio and other instances of Visual Studio 2015, so I know this is a problem not with the code but with my configuration.

Answer (score 3):

I believe what you're asking is answered here in this other SO question:

[How come there's no IKernel implementation in Ninject.Portable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24757186/how-come-theres-no-ikernel-implementation-in-ninject-portable)

Ninject needs platform specific code to work in each Xamarin Platform, so, for a Xamarin project I would suggest you use the Ninject.Portable NuGet package instead of the plain Ninject one. You also need to install the NuGet in Droid, iOS, Tests and UITests projects to be able to compile all the Solution.

Best Regards